# Backup ubuntu and eliminate windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, virtualbox, windows-7, backup

Laptop is currently configured for dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows7, Windows7 was the original OS, Ubuntu 14.4 was added later. 500G harddrive has multiple partitions. VirtualBox was added under Ubuntu and has multiple VMs.

I want to eliminate the old Windows7, eliminate the harddrive multiple partitions, run Ubuntu as the single bootable OS & keep the multiple VMs under VirtualBox.

Keeping the multiple VirtualBox VMs looks doable, if complex and I have plenty of backup disk space. I would rather not re-install Ubuntu as I have been adding to it regularly but will if I have to.

Any suggestions, guidance would be helpful.

Comment: I have this open in edit view so I can't really add an answer but all you need to do is run an ubuntu livecd, open gparted, delete the partitions you don't want and resize the others, then run a grub update operation to make sure everything is looking in the right place when it boots. Hope I helped!

Answer (score 2):

First off, make sure you backup everything you've got on the Windows partitions. I would then suggest trying [gparted.](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/) It might let you remove the existing Windows partitions and expand the Ubuntu partitions without losing any data (depending on how the partitions are laid out).

Comment: This is correct. You should be able to delete the windows partition and expand the Ubuntu partition. Data on the windows partition will be lost (hence the backup). Data on the Ubuntu partition, including your VMs (assuming they are on that partition) will be unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
sudo cfdisk
```

If you dont know how to use cfdisk [this](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Cfdisk_Basic_Partitioning_Scenarios) might help

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question as you haven't put a valid method. They need to know what to do with the command.

Comment: I've posted a link if you could read

Comment: Posting a link doesn't help. You have to put the solution in your answer. It's one of Ask Ubuntu's guidelines to constructive answers.

Comment: Okay , I'll keep it in mind from next time